How to use an image from device's file system for adb emu virtualscene-image table command?
I am able to use adb emu virtualscene-image table <image> command to set the image on the table but it only works for files that are in the file system where adb server runs.
Is there a way to use images in the file system where adb client runs? Or file system of the device after running adb push?
I checked the codebase of adb to understand how it works but couldn't find the part of this command specifically.
